# Id of object mus be removed based on matching req.params.id

Tags: node.js, express

```js
router.delete('/shopping-cart/:id', (req, res) => {
    let cart = new Cart(req.session.cart);
    console.log(req.params.id);
    console.log(cart.generateArray());
});
```

console.log will output the following result (req.params.id):

5c863cc8ee0819f989acf9c3

console.log will output the following result (cart.generateArray()):

```
[ { item: 
 { _id: '5c863cc8ee0819f989acf9c3',
   imagePath: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/5e/Gothiccover.png',
   title: 'Gothic Video',
   description: 'Absolutely stunning',
   price: 10,
   __v: 0 },
image: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/5e/Gothiccover.png',
qty: 1,
price: 10,
id: '5c863cc8ee0819f989acf9c3' } ]
```

So how do I loop through all the items and check if id matches the req.params.id. If that is the case, it should remove that object and then return an updated array on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

```
let cards = [{
    item: {
        _id: '5c863cc8ee0819f989acf9c3',
        imagePath: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/5e/Gothiccover.png',
        title: 'Gothic Video',
        description: 'Absolutely stunning',
        price: 10,
        __v: 0,
    },
    image: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/5e/Gothiccover.png',
    qty: 1,
    price: 10,
    id: '5c863cc8ee0819f989acf9c3',
}]

cards.forEach(element => {
    delete element.id
})

console.info(cards)
```

Comment: I want to check id first and then remove the object itself which is in tis case item, how should I do that

Answer (score 0):

I assume that is coming from `cart.generateArray()`?

If so, you probably should do that inside the function in question, but if you can't, then just map the results to a new array:

```
let result = cart.generateArray().map(item => {
  const {id, ...entry} = item;
  // if you want to also remove _id from the inner item, you can do the same
  return entry;
});
console.log(result); // will have entries w/o id in them.
```

If you're looking to remove the nested `item` object as well, it's the smae approach, though I'll change some words to improve readability.

```
let result = cart.generateArray().map(cartItem => {
  const {id, item, ...entry} = cartItem;
  // this will remove both the id and the item keys
  return entry;
});
console.log(result); // will have entries w/o id in them.
```

Comment: But how do I remove the item where the id belongs to?

Comment: I'm sorry, you're asking about removing the nested `item` object as well?  Just the same way.  I'll add to the answer.

Comment: This would not remove the object of id in this case

Comment: @front end The structure the you posted has only one item.  Are you saying it might not have the matching I’d?